# Power BI : System.InvalidOperationException: Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, iis, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

We are facing following error when deployed project in IIS, And it is working fine when ran from visual studio.

Error at when calling below method to get AccessToken

```
return authContext.AcquireToken(this.PowerBiAPI, this.ClientID, new Uri(this.RedirectUrl)).AccessToken;
```

Error is :

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 
Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in
UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly 
style to display a notification from a service application.
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.RunAsyncTask[T](Task`1 task)
at DSLUI.Controllers.BusinessLogic.ReportService.GetAccessToken()
```

Here this.ClientID is generated for App Type: Native

web : https://dev.powerbi.com/apps

If anyone have any idea regarding above error, please help us.

Answer (score 0):

As i am using App type Native,AAD popup comming at server side causing this issue.

Then i changes it to App Type to Web app, and getting access token using  below code, Issue got resolved.

```
public async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
    {
        try
        {
            var password = Utility.Decrypt(this.PWBI_Psw);

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                 {
                 new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
                 new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "openid"),
                 new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", this.PWBI_User),
                 new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password),
                 new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", this.ClientID),
                 new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", this.ClientSecretKey),
                 new KeyValuePair<string, string>("resource", this.PowerBiAPI)
                 });

            string tokenEndpointUri = string.Format(this.TokenEndpointUri, this.TenantID);
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                HttpResponseMessage res = client.PostAsync(tokenEndpointUri, content).Result;

                string json = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
                var AccessToken = (string)obj["access_token"];

                return AccessToken;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for returning and posting your solution.